# What effect does Faction Wrath have?

Tags: tyranny

Factions have both a Favor and Wrath bar under Reputations.

So far it looks like Favor makes them more likely to tell me things, and makes them nicer to me, but I haven't seen anything opened up or specifically closed off by Wrath.

It looks like they are not opposites, I can have both Favor and Wrath so I assume it is not all "bad".

But what does Wrath actually do?